# How to display an img in a MUI X DataGrid column?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

Being a React newbie I have first created [a test project with MUI Table](https://github.com/afarber/react-questions/tree/main/top-list), which works well enough:

[image: screenshot one]

However I would like to have pagination and sortable columns, when displaying my data.

So I have created [another test project using MUI X DataGrid](https://github.com/afarber/react-questions/tree/main/top-grid):

[image: screenshot two]

As you can see it kind of works, but the last column displays my HTML img code verbatim.

I have tried to use value getter for that in [my custom TopGrid.jsx component](https://github.com/afarber/react-questions/blob/main/top-grid/src/components/TopGrid.jsx):

```
const wrongImgHandler = (photo) => {
  return photo && PHOTO_PATTERN.test(photo) ? photo : "female_sad.png";
};

const imgErrorHandler = ({ currentTarget }) => {
  // prevents looping
  currentTarget.onerror = null;
  currentTarget.src = "male_sad.png";
};

const columns = [
  {
    field: "elo",
    headerName: "Elo",
    type: "number",
    width: 90,
  },
  {
    field: "given",
    headerName: "First name",
    width: 150,
  },
  {
    field: "photo",
    headerName: "Photo",
    sortable: false,
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: (params) =>
      `<img
        src=${wrongImgHandler(params.row.photo)}
        className="avatar"
        onError=${imgErrorHandler}
      />`,
  },
];
```

Please advise me, how to display an img element with onError handler in a MUI X DataGrid.

Comment: Use the `renderCell` property in your columns definition. It allows you to override what's displayed in the cell by rendering any reactnode (JSX fragment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @super, the [renderCell](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#rendering-cells) has worked for me:

[image: screenshot]

```
function Avatar({ photo }) {
  const wrongImgHandler = (photo) => {
    return photo && PHOTO_PATTERN.test(photo) ? photo : "female_sad.png";
  };

  const imgErrorHandler = ({ currentTarget }) => {
    // prevents looping
    currentTarget.onerror = null;
    currentTarget.src = "male_sad.png";
  };

  return (
    <img
      src={wrongImgHandler(photo)}
      className="avatar"
      onError={imgErrorHandler}
    />
  );
}

Avatar.propTypes = {
  photo: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

const columns = [
  {
    field: "elo",
    headerName: "Elo",
    type: "number",
  },
  {
    field: "given",
    headerName: "First name",
    width: 200,
  },
  {
    field: "photo",
    headerName: "Photo",
    align: "center",
    sortable: false,
    renderCell: (params) => <Avatar photo={params.row.photo} />,
  },
];
```